# how to insert my code JS in mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, and I want to store JavaScript code snippets in a MySQL database,in a table named `tag` in order to do an automatic tracking. How can I do that?

Here is my snippet of code that exists in the code of my Node.js server

```
$(document).ready(function(data) {
 $('#poke').click(function(){
        socket.emit('alarm')
        })
   });
```

`poke` is the ID of my button.

This is my table `tag`, where I want to insert my JavaScript code:

[image]

Comment: Even though this is an unusual and unsafe requirement, have you used the `varchar`field?

Comment: JavaScript code is just text. If you want to store it in a database (which is not generally a good idea), you store it just like text.

Comment: *"Here is my snippet of code that exists in the code of my Node.js server"* That clearly isn't Node.js code. It's client-side browser code.

Comment: no i wonna to track users , i tried to create some tags , ho are 
JavaScript code snippet, and to make my tracking automatic I have to store them in a mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Use following query - I assume that you put code to 'name' column - working example [here](https://paiza.io/projects/e/Bi_hScU_yWW_nJZ5A8GneQ))

```
insert into tag(tag_id, type, action_id,  name) values(1,1,1, "
$(document).ready(function(data) {
 $('#poke').click(function(){
        socket.emit('alarm')
        })
   });
");
```

Answer (score 0):

The page from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) explains the SQL syntax in more detail:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```